# Change MX record to another server

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server, mx-record

I have a host-machine with Centos 7 and a guest machine with Centos 6.6. I want my guest to be a mail server on dedicated static ip for all my domains (on the same host-ip and not). P.S. I use Postfix+Dovecot.

F.e. my guest's hostname (mail server) is mail.example.com and it has an ip 1.1.1.1, and my example.com ip is not 1.1.1.1. If I understand everything correct I need:

1. Change MX record for example.com to mail.example.com
2. Add A record "mail" for example.com and point it to 1.1.1.1
3. Change MX records on all my domains to mail.example.com
4. Remove A records "mail" from all my domains except example.com

I've never done this before, so please confirm if I understand right all I need to do. Will such mail server configuration be ok from the site of anti-spam services? Please suggest the correct to-do list for my wanted configuration!

Comment: sounds about right, not really q and a ... more like suggest me something...

Comment: thanks, I'm just trying to never push buttons without understanding what I am doing:)

Comment: From the spec you gave, all your steps are fine.

Answer (score 0):

refer to one of these:

- [MX record - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record)
- [16.3. Zone Files](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-bind-zone.html)